# How to access a UITextView on another ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I am trying to equal the string of an UITextView from anotherViewController to the MainViewController . I mean users write something in UITextView from anotherViewController and when touch the done button the string in UITextView should equal to another string in MainViewController . How can I access UITextView ???

I did something like this but did not get any result  !

```
#import "AnotherViewController"

@class AnotherViewController;

@interface MainViewContoller : UIViewController {

    NSString *main_string;
    AnotherViewController *textEntered;

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

textEntered.TEXT = main_string

}
```

***TEXT is the name my UITextView on AnotherViewController .

EDITED :

```
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextView *TEXT;
    id  delegate;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *TEXT;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) id delegate;

@end


@implementation AnotherViewController
@synthesize TEXT ,delegate;


- (IBAction)doneButton {

    //!!! problem with compare ! the compiler got me some warning 
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER

```
#import "AnotherViewController.h"


@class Another...;

@interface MainViewControlelr : UIViewController {

NSString *main_string;

TextViewController *textEntered;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    textEntered.delegate = self;
    }


- (void) compareText {

    [textEntered.TEXT isEqual:main_string];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set mainViewController object as the delegate of an object of anotherViewController type. And use that delegate from AnotherViewController to pass messages to MainViewController.

Inside MainViewController, when you create your AnotherViewController object do:

```
anotherVC.delegate = self;
```

And in AnotherViewController, when your button action is done and you want to pass the text back, say store in a string. Then pass it to MainViewController as:

```
[delegate compareText:textView.text];
```

compareText with a NSString argument would be a method in your MainViewController class.

EDIT:

In your AnotherViewController.h interface, declare an ivar:

```
id delegate;
```

Then use @property (in .h) and @synthesize (in .m) for getter and setter.

Then do the above.

Comment: how can I set my mainViewController as the delegate ? would you please write the code ? I am little novice

Comment: sorry , would you please explain more about compareText ??

Comment: compareText: is a method that you would write in MainViewController accepting a NSString as argument. That argument would be the one it would receive from the [delegate compareText:yourString]. Where yourString would be the textView's text. Got it?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how write the compareText method ! for example -(void) compareText :

Comment: inside compareText method, just compare both strings (the string in MainViewController and the string argument you get). Use [str1 isEqualToString:str2]. Where str1 is the string in your MainViewController and str2 is the argument you get it. Returns 1 if both are same strings.

Comment: sorry I did not get any result ! but I am trying ... see my edited post plz

Answer (score 0):

I think you created an AnotherViewController pointer but did not set it.

before you can access textEntered.TEXT, you should set you textEntered pointer to your AnotherViewController object.

Here is how:

on iGhalamViewController class, create a property for setting textEntered object like this in your interface declaration (probably in iGhalamViewController.h)

```
@property (assign) AnotherViewController *textEntered;
```

So, at the root place where do you create this viewcontroller objects both. After you create AnotherViewController and iGhalamViewController, set your textEntered pointer like this.

```
AnotherViewController* a = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithBlah:blah];
iGhalamViewController* b = [[iGhalamViewController alloc] initWithBlah:blah];
b.textEntered = a;
```

Then it should work like you expected. But use it in other method than viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad probaby gets called before you can set textEntered. A button press event method should be fine.

Comment: blah ! !! :D I need some sufficient way

Comment: sorry, but there is two **sufficient** ways to solve is; one is above, Bourne's answer, delegation. one is this, just referencing.

Comment: Thank you , would you please write the tested code  ? I am novice :(