# iOS - equal the UITextView string on the different viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

How can i  equal a UITextView strings with  another UItextView on different viewControllers

on ViewController1 :

```
UItextView *textView1;
```

on ViewController2 :

```
UITextView *textView2;
```

so when user enter some text in "textView" on ViewController2  the string of textView should be equal with textLayer on ViewController1

I don't know how can I relate each other ! with button on ViewController2 something like this :

```
-(IBAction)Done {
[textView2.Text isEqualToString:textView1];
}
```

and on the ViewController1 should change the string of textView2 as textView1 something like this:

```
textView1.string = ViewController2.textView2;
```

Is there is possible way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you wish to reach a viewcontroller objects' variable from other?

see: [How to access a UITextView on another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472925/how-to-access-a-uitextview-on-another-viewcontroller)